# Почему laravel из коробки медленно работает?

Tags: laravel, производительность

Создал проект ларавель:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel fresh
```

Запускаю сервер

```
php artisan serve
```

Постменом захожу на локалхост, время отклика 600мс
Переношу весь проект на рабочий сервер, получаю 550мс. При этом на нем же другие сайты работают с откликом 2-5 мс

Что может быть, ведь пустой проект, даже оптимизировать нечего
Локальный комп с ссд, как и сервер

Подскажите, что может быть не так настроено?

Comment: APP_ENV=production и APP_DEBUG=false попробуйте в .env

Comment: Выставил эти значения, перезапустил сервер - не помогло

Comment: вообще не совсем понимаю, как вы хотите загрузить главную страницу сайта  за 5мс? У меня на свежем проекте это занимает примерно 175мс на локальном хосте

Comment: На сервере есть другой сайт, не на ларавеле, и он открывается мгновенно.

Comment: laravel же тянет много всего на фоне, пока не выдаст ответ. Если вам нужно меньшее время отклика, то смотрите в сторону lumen. Ну или пишите сайт с нуля без фреймворков готовых - там да, будет всё мгновенно открываться.

Comment: Да, тот сайт написан на чистом php. Но вот в чем дело. Я не обращал внимания на эту задержку, пока не увидел на ютубе, что задержка 24мс при чистой установке

Comment: Lumen отдаёт ответ за примерно 55-60мс у меня сейчас на локальном хосте. В lumen меньше зависимотсей тянется, поэтому быстрее работает. Вы экономите на спичках, мне кажется.

Comment: А если сделать все шаги, описанные тут https://laravel.com/docs/master/deployment#optimization?